# Shell Scripting - io redirecting - precedence of operators

Tags: shell, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

could somebody explain the difference between these two codes?

```
bad_command 2>&  >> file.out
```

and

```
bad_command >> file.out 2>&
```

The manual said that these two codes are different,and first command will
output nothing to file.out.

**So , here are my questions.**

1/ what is the reason for that?

2/ Is there is a document which describes how operator precedence works in shell?
   how shell parses and made it's syntax tree.

3/ What is the correct syntax and order of it?

--Thanks in advance--

Comment: You should try to accept correct answers, it helps SO work more efficiently, and means people are more willing to help you.

Comment: @AlexHadley am I seeding a duplicate? I have searched for this, but I didn't find it.

Comment: I mean the questions you have asked previously, you need to go back to them and mark an answer as correct if there was a correct answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are syntactically wrong. I assume you meant

```
bad_command 2>&1  >> file.out
```

and

```
bad_command >> file.out 2>&1
```

instead.

Between these, there is a difference. Redirections are imperative statements, which are worked through from left to right. A redirection operates on a process' **file descriptors (fds)**. You might have heard of the standard filedescriptors #0 (standard in/stdin), #1 (standard out/stdout), #2 (standard error/stderr).

The first commandline's redirections read: "Make fd 2 a copy of fd 1, but then change fd 1 to append to 'file.out'" (the second redirection has no effect to fd 2, which still is a copy of what fd 1 was at the beginning)

The seconds ones read: "Change fd 1 to append to 'file.out', and then make fd 2 a copy of fd 1" (the first redirection has effect to the second redirection, bot fds are now the same)

Comment: so what about the `operator precedence` document? is it non-existing?

Comment: @n611x007, What operator precedence document do you mean exactly?