# Cat in terminal seems to behave erratically random

Tags: shell, terminal, cat

I have a file, with the following content:

```
2)    Wiegley   Maths      90
3)    Artur     Biology    87
4)    Drew      English    85
5)    Phils     History    89
```

I store it in a file, called `marks.txt`.

In shell, I ran some operations with `sed` and `awk` (with xfce4 terminal emulator)

```
awk '{print $3 "\t" $4}' marks.txt | sed -e '/^E/d' > foo.txt | cat foo.txt
```

When I execute the same command fast (arrow up and enter), it gives me sometimes the output of the file `foo.txt`. But sometimes it gives me no output, when repeating the same command fast.

I fail to understand this, what it seems as a random behaviour, from my shell. Can anyone explain why `cat` gives sometimes the output, when I repeat the same command fast? Would it not be waiting on the output of the `awk` and `sed` first?

Comment: What are expecting `| cat foo.txt` to do? It's almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @Tom I'm not talking about the rightness or wrongness. I'm trying to understand why the terminal sometimes display the output, and sometimes not while the command is the same. Feel free to try it out, then you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your issue is related to precedence between pipe and redirection.

> Splitting a command line into piped commands is done *before* doing
>   file redirection.  File redirection happens second, and if present,
>   has precedence over pipe redirection.  (The file redirection always
>   wins.)

From : http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~mcrob/toolbox/unix/redirection

You can found some examples here :

[Pipe | Redirection < > Precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942042/pipe-redirection-precedence)

Answer (score 2):

The pipe to `cat` is meaningless because you're not passing any data across it, or attempting to use it (to do this, you would use `cat -`).

Your command opens three subshells. The `>` in the middle will truncate the file `foo.txt` before waiting for any input. `cat foo.txt` will attempt to access the file `foo.txt` at *more or less* the same time. Depending on which of these two things happens first, `foo.txt` will either contain the contents from the previous time you ran the command or it will be empty.

For the record, your command would be better written as:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '$3 !~ /^E/ { print $3, $4 }' marks.txt > foo.txt
```

If you would like to print the result to standard output and write to the file at the same time, one option would be to use `tee`.

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '$3 !~ /^E/ { print $3, $4 }' marks.txt | tee foo.txt
```

This prints the third and fourth field of any line whose third field doesn't start with `E`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. How could I 'measure'/detect if `cat foo.txt` is accessing the file `foo.txt`, while `>` is trying to truncate the file `foo.txt`? It seems to me that sometimes the `cat` command is earlier before the output gets written. I would like to understand in which circumstances the `cat` is earlier.

Comment: You're basically asking three programs to run at the same time and the OS is trying to honour that request. I'm not sure that the output can be predicted in any reliable way. You could use another tool to [detect whether the file is open](http://superuser.com/q/97844/385589) but by the time this has run, it may well have been closed.