# Terminal Piping and Writing to File

Tags: terminal, pipe, zsh

I am trying to copy the first two items in my 'Downloads' directory using only the terminal.

I open up zsh, cd into my 'Downloads' directory and start typing.
The below reflects what is shown in the terminal:

```
% ls -lt | head -3
file1.csv
file2.csv  (exactly the files I want)
  
% ls -lt | head -3 > ToBeCopied.txt
% vim ToBeCopied.txt

total 24625744
-rw-r--r--   1 Aaron  staff            0 22 Apr 15:28 ToBeCopied.txt
-rw-r--r--@  1 Aaron  staff        42042 22 Apr 15:16 file1.csv
```

What happened to file2.csv?

Comment: The redirection to stdout executed before the `ls` command started. That file is newer than any other file in that folder. It made file2.csv appear later in the list. Redirect your output somewhere else and you'll be fine.

Comment: "somewhere else" being "not to a file in the same directory"

Comment: @JeffHolt I thought the flow for `ls -lt | head -3` would be: 1. list the files in current directory according to time 2. Pipe that output to the `head` command

Comment: @AaronLee See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12942042/1707353) for more information on operator precedence. I would SMH if any shell deviated from what was established 51 years ago. If you search SO for questions asked/week about writing a shell for class, you'll better understand why things work the way they do.