# LLVM14, why i can't use opt --print option?

Tags: llvm

I build the LLVM from source in release edtion.Now get the loop or cycle information is what i need.But it just can't work.

```
    $opt -passes=print<cycles>  input.ll -o /dev/null               
    zsh: no such file or directory: cycles
```

Comment: "opt -enable-new-pm=0 -analyze -loops input.bc" This one get work, but it use the legacy pass manager. And "passes=print<cycles>" still can't work. Don't konw why..

Answer (score 0):

The unix command `opt -passes=print<cycles>  input.ll` means to run the command `opt -passes=print` while reading from the file named `cycles` and writing to the file named `input.ll`.

Have a look at [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942042) for more about this shell syntax.

You may want to use `opt -passes='print<cycles>'`, that will at least not be interpreted by the shell, but I fear that won't work either. I've no idea what `print<cycles>` is supposed to achieve.